# Add a deep link to a text message

Tags: android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

Trying to add a link to a text message that will link to open my app.
The link is helloapp:// and when that is typed into safari it opens the app. I have used deep linking with React Native to achieve this.

When I insert that into the text it comes up as a string. Is there a way to link to the app with a link? Basically I want to create a hyperlink with this link helloapp://

I have tried link shorteners but it does not recognise the url and will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios/) to add Universal Link to the app.

Although in the new version of xcode. Adding the Associated Domains is done by clicking the + sign to left of capability when on the Signing & Capabilities tab.

This solved the issue without Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Universal Links. I prefer to use Firebase Dynamic Links https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage

Comment: Not using Firebase anywhere in the app unfortunately. Is there an alternative or is this the only solution?

Comment: You will still need to create a website, Firebase simplifies this https://www.ekreative.com/blog/universal-linking-in-react-native-for-ios/

Comment: I sorted it with Universal links. By following this https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios/